# Linux Centos issue with MS SQL Using FreeTDS

Tags: php, linux, pdo, centos, freetds

I have gone though all of the steps in the following link:

http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/definitive-freetds-installation-instructions-88561.html

Everything seems to install properly (I don't recieve any errors), but yet when I attempt to use mssql_connect() I get a 500 error.

I have read through the comments and have even attempted what they suggest and still it continues to return a 500 error.

I am unsure of what needs to be done to resolve this, I know there is also the use if PDO() but I would need to get the dblib driver, which I'm unsure of how to go about installing that.

Some additional info that could be helpful is if the server specified is incorrect then it will return that it can't connect. Thus the 500 error is only happening when the connection should be functioning.

The error log has the following:

`[Tue Dec 16 10:56:04.475895 2014] [core:error] [pid 19276] [client 108.161.166.157:52228] End of script output before headers: connection.php`

Comment: did you look at the server's error log to get details about the 500?

Comment: Where can I find the proper error log file, I have found a few different ones and they don't seem to correspond to this.

Comment: assuming apache, then /var/log/httpd or something like that. it'd be defined in the httpd.conf anyways.